# Как задать центр вращения обьекта?

Tags: three.js

Собственно на Three.js есть цилиндр. Требуется повернуть цилиндр вокруг точки. По смотрел документацию, но ничего дельного не смог найти (или не там искал). Как можно задать точку вращения объекту?

Comment: А можно поясняющую картинку хотя бы, для лучшего понимания - как оно сейчас, как оно должно быть?

Comment: сейчас он вращается вокруг центра?

Comment: не ясно - что надо в итоге ) вокруг какой точки? что именно повернуть: меш или геометрию?